# Mac m1, disassemble to x86 instructions using virtual machine

Tags: assembly, arm, virtual-machine, intel

I have a mac m1 with an arm processor and I wanted to learn a bit about x86 assembly (I know nothing about assembly). I was told that a virtual machine can emulate everything (CPU,...). So is it possible to use [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/) to emulate the x86 processor and when I disassemble some code will I see x86 assembly code?

Comment: Disassembly depends on what architecture the machine code was for.  `llvm-objdump -d` works on any object files / executables it knows about, regardless of what architecture `llvm-objdump` itself is running on.  e.g. my x86-64 Linux desktop can disassemble the things I built with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`, or 32-bit ARM, or `clang -target mips -c` or various other architectures.  Of course to actually *run* x86 executables (and single-step them in a debugger which is essential for learning assembly quickly and efficiently), you'll need some kind of VM or emulator, yes.  Maybe not just Rosetta.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting. Are you suggesting that if I compile test.c in test.o on my mac m1, `llvm-objdump` -d will let me see the disassembly for x86 as well? What is the command to do that? I looked at the man page of llvm-objdump but got a bit lost.

Comment: Only if you compile it for x86, with a cross-compiler.  That's the important part.  `clang` can do that, because it's set up to build executables for Intel or ARM64 Macs, but I think doesn't by default.  Google how to compile Intel executables on an M1 mac.  `llvm-objdump -d` can't give you x86 disassembly for a native ARM64 executable; there's no x86 machine code in there to disassemble.  Disassembly is just transforming between binary machine code and text assembly language, pretty much 1:1 instructions.